# perror() prints 'Unknown error -number', instead of 'message' when setting errno manually in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, system-calls, errno

Im writing an assembly code to write bytes in a file descriptor, using *nasm* and *gcc* in Linux. I want to recreate the behaviour of the C function **write**. If the fd is wrong, or if the address to write is NULL, I set the errno value by calling `extern __errno_location`(Linux definition) to the code error number, and then the return (rax) to -1, as the **write** function does.

```
            section .text
            global  ft_my_write
            extern  __errno_location

ft_my_write:
        mov     rax, 1      ;syscall write, rax = 1, rdi = fd, rsi = char*, rdx = num bytes
        syscall
        cmp     rax, 0
        jl      error
        ret
error:
        push    rax
        call    __errno_location wrt ..plt  ;wrt..pl avoids overflow in R_X86_64_PC32 relocation
        mov     rdi, rax
        pop     rax
        mov     [rdi], rax
        mov     rax, -1
        ret
```

Now if I use it with a wrong example, like bad fd or NULL address, I see I got the correct *errno* number (got from the *rax* value from the write syscall): -9 and -14, but the perror() message prints *Unknown error*, instead of *Bad file descriptor* or *Bad address* message that the original **write** function prints.

```
int i,j;
i = ft_my_write(-1, "hello\n", 5);
perror("errno");       -------------------> prints 'errno: Unknown error -9'
j = write(-1, "hello\n", 5);
perror("errno");       -------------------> prints 'errno: Bad file descriptor'     
printf ("num bytes = %d (%d)\n", i, j); --> prints 'num bytes = -1 (-1)'
```

Similarly

```
int i,j;
i = ft_my_write(11, NULL, 5);
perror("errno");       -------------------> prints 'errno: Unknown error -14' 
j = write(1, NULL, 5);
perror("errno");       -------------------> prints 'errno: Bad address'     
printf ("num bytes = %d (%d)\n", i, j); --> prints 'num bytes = -1 (-1)'
```

Where this difference comes frome? why *perror()* seems not to correctly interpret the error code although *errno* is apparently set to its correct value?

Comment: You need to first negate the error number.  Also note that `errno` is an `int`, so use `mov [rdi], eax` to write to it.

Comment: great, it worked. I had understood that the errno error values are negative, between -1 and -4095. arent they negatives?

Comment: The syscall return values are -1 to -4095 but they represent the positive numbers of errors 1 to 4095.

Comment: Errno values are positive, but the Linux kernel has the convention of returning `-errno` both in its internal implementation and in its syscall interface. This has the advantage that only one register is required for output.  Other systems that don't use this convention normally use two registers (or one register plus a bit in flags register) as syscall output.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the value of errno (value that you modify after using errno_location) needs to be positive.  The kernel ABI returns `-errno` on error; a value from -4095 .. -1, just to make it possible to distinguish error from success.

You can use `neg eax` to have it in positive.

(Note that it's `int errno`, you should only be storing a dword not a qword into the pointer you get from `__errno_location`)